# TinyMCE react, incoming data can not render dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, model-view-controller, tinymce, tinymce-4

I work on JS/React on frontend and Java backend.

TinyMCE has nice MoxieManager which works pretty well but on PHP and .NET. I created then my own file browser. I use Observer pattern for transfering data in MVC. The problem is that, when I receive (for example, url to picture) in TinyMCE react part it does not render dynamically. It only render when I open again the dialog with nested picture.

Of course I call setState when I reassign new value (incoming value) to current in React.

Any suggestions?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Once the component gets the initial value to display, it takes over, so updating the initial value has no effect. Try forcing a re-render of the component, the way I'm doing it is by changing the `key` attribute to trick react into thinking it's a different instance of the component

```
<TinyMCE
    key={aRandomValueThatChangesWhenIncomingValue} // this line makes the trick
    content={yourContent}
    config={{
        plugins: "link image lists print preview",
        toolbar:
            "undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist",
    }}
    onChange={handleEditorChange}
/>
```